# How to compare output of two panda's group by functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df's which I created after executing group by of 2 dataframes. I need to join these two summary outputs to check if there is a difference in hours claimed.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Week": ["3/30/2018", "3/30/2018", "3/30/2018", "3/23/2018",
                             "3/23/2018","3/16/2018", "3/16/2018", "3/9/2018",
                             "3/9/2018"],
                    "Empl": ["Sam", "John", "Mike", "Sam", "Mike","Sam",
                             "John", "Mike", "Sam"],
                    "Hrs": [11, 12, 2, 13, 5, 14, 15, 16, 7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Week": ["3/30/2018", "3/30/2018", "3/30/2018", "3/23/2018",
                             "3/16/2018", "3/16/2018", "3/9/2018", "3/9/2018"],
                    "Empl": ["Sam", "John", "Mike", "Sam", "Mike","Sam",  "Mike", "Sam"],
                    "Hrs": [16, 12, 2, 13, 5, 15, 21, 7]})

gdF1 = df1.groupby(["Week","Empl"])["Hrs"].sum()
gdF2 = df2.groupby(["Week","Empl"])["Hrs"].sum()

# need to join gdF1 and gDF2 on Week and Empl for further comparison.
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. So just by addin as_index = False the output gets changed from Series to a Dataframe ? I see the difference in output creared when gdF1 = df1.groupby(["Week","Empl"])["Hrs"].sum() and gdF1 = df1.groupby(["Week","Empl"],as_index=False)["Hrs"].sum() first case its pandas.core.series.Series and second case pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.

Comment: yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `as_index=False` in groupby then you can join them for further analysis:

```
gdF1 = df1.groupby(["Week","Empl"],as_index=False)["Hrs"].sum()
gdF2 = df2.groupby(["Week","Empl"],as_index=False)["Hrs"].sum()
or
gdF1 = df1.groupby(["Week","Empl"])["Hrs"].sum().reset_index(drop=True)
gdF2 = df2.groupby(["Week","Empl"])["Hrs"].sum().reset_index(drop=True)
In [6]: gdF1
Out[6]: 
        Week  Empl  Hrs
0  3/16/2018  John   15
1  3/16/2018   Sam   14
2  3/23/2018  Mike    5
3  3/23/2018   Sam   13
4  3/30/2018  John   12
5  3/30/2018  Mike    2
6  3/30/2018   Sam   11
7   3/9/2018  Mike   16
8   3/9/2018   Sam    7

In [7]: gdF2
Out[7]: 
        Week  Empl  Hrs
0  3/16/2018  Mike    5
1  3/16/2018   Sam   15
2  3/23/2018   Sam   13
3  3/30/2018  John   12
4  3/30/2018  Mike    2
5  3/30/2018   Sam   16
6   3/9/2018  Mike   21
7   3/9/2018   Sam    7
```